# Dynamic Column Name in LinQ

Tags: linq, list, dynamic

I am having a class Item.

```
class Item{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set;}
    }
```

I want to filter list of items based on dynamic column name.
Suppose I want list of Names then Column Name is "Name" and result will be list of names
If column name is Description, I need list of descriptions.

How to do this with LinQ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Easy, just select the property you need from the list:

```
var items = new List<Item>();
//get names
var names = items.Select(x => x.Name);
//get descriptions
var descriptions = items.Select(x => x.Description);
```

**Update:**

You'll need a bit of reflection to do this:

```
var names = items.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(x));
```

Throw this in a method for re-usability:

```
public IEnumerable<object> GetColumn(List<Item> items, string columnName)
{
    var values = items.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(x));
    return values;
}
```

Of course this doesn't validate wether the column exists in the object. So it will throw a `NullReferenceException` when it doesn't. It returns an `IEnumerable<object>`, so you'll have to call `ToString()` on each object afterwards to get the value or call the `ToString()` in the query right after `GetValue(x)`:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetColumn(List<Item> items, string columnName)
{
    var values = items.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(x).ToString());
    return values;
}
```

Usage:

```
var items = new List<Item>(); //fill it up
var result = GetColumn(items, "Name");
```

Comment: `items` should be of type `List<string>`, shouldn't it?

Comment: No, the class is `Item` so it should be a list of that type. `names` and `descriptions` will be an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Don't know what I interpreted in you code - Sorry

Comment: Here you have written two queries. For retrieving names and second for descriptions. I need one query which is generalized.

Comment: If column doesn't exists, it will give NullReferenceException. How to handle this exception?

Comment: This is not a good solution if you're pulling large amounts of data from db.