# LINQ how to pass method variable as column name in where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a probleme with my code below. I want to pass my variable (relance) as columnname in my where clause but ...... It doesn't work . I need your help.

```
 public IList<ImportDataViewModel> LienNroList(string colName)
    {
        IEnumerable<ImportDataViewModel> result = new List<ImportDataViewModel>();
        IEnumerable<ImportDataViewModel> ImportDataViewModel = new List<ImportDataViewModel>();

        var col1 = context.col1;
        var col2 = context.col2;
        var col3 = context.col3;
        var col4 = context.col4;

        result = col1
           .GroupJoin(col2, Lien => Lien.code_INSEE, jdo => jdo.Ref_codeINSEE, (Lien, jdo) => new { Lien, jdo })
           .GroupJoin(col3, Lien => Lien.Lien.id, comm => comm.id_pf, (Lien, comm) => new { Lien.Lien, Lien.jdo, comm })
           .GroupJoin(col4, LienRest => LienRest.Lien.id, rel => rel.id_pf, (LienRest, rel) => new { rel, LienRest.Lien, LienRest.jdo }).DefaultIfEmpty()
           .Where(x => x.Lien.colName <= DateTime.Now)
           .SelectMany(LienNro => LienNro.rel.DefaultIfEmpty(), (rel, Lien) => new ImportDataViewModel()

           {});
```

Comment: What's in `context` and what's `context.colxx`? are those `context.colxx` are columns or tables? why do you `groupjoin` columns? why don't you use good code naming, like `colName` should be `columnName` , so are other variables..... what's `Lien` and `Nro`...

Comment: Reflection would be one way. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732724/dynamic-column-name-in-linq/24732863)

Comment: [DynamicLinq](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic) could also be used. Without that or Reflection, you must use `if`/`else` or `switch`/`case` and test for each `colName` value and add the appropriate `Where`.